# Как узнать, поддерживает ли компилятор MinGW какой-либо стандарт С++?

Tags: c++, mingw, c++17

Проблема следующая: я не знаю, какой стандарт С++ (C++11, C++14, C++17, C++20) поддерживает компилятор (MinGW), ***установленный*** сейчас на ПК.
Какой способ есть узнать это?

Comment: Для начала вызовите в консоли `g++ --version`, а потом можно поискать, какие стандарты реализваны в этой версии

Comment: @avp Спасибо большое, посмотрел, вопрос выяснил. Но, для общего развития, есть ли какой-то вариант без доступа в интернет узнать по поводу поддержки какого-либо стандарта (не сохраняя таблицы с информацией, т.е имея только голый компилятор под рукой)?

Comment: В linux это `man g++` и в консольном выводе вводите `/-std=<Enter>`, далее вводом `/<Enter>` ищете описание. В винде -- не знаю

Comment: @avp Спасибо, еще один повод перейти на linux.

Comment: Стандарт может поддерживаться *не полностью*. Но можно пробовать компилировать разные вещи, которые появлялись в том или ином стандарте. Кстати, посмотрите сюда: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support

Comment: Если известен компилятор и его версия, можно посмотреть [таблицы поддержки стандарта языка](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support). Ещё есть [предопределённый макрос `__cplusplus`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/replace) (хотя в общем случае, к сожалению, он не всегда раскрывается в правильное значение). Если наверняка известно, что используется C++20 или выше, можно проверять поддержку отдельных аспектов языка с помощью большого множества [специальных макросов](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/feature_test).

Comment: Поддержку конкретного стандарта подвозят не сразу целиком, поэтому проверять целиком С++?? нет большого смысла (только чтобы узнать, какой флажок передавать для последнего стандарта, но это и `--help` скажет). Имеет смысл проверять отдельные фичи (см. ссылку в предыдущем комменте). *"еще один повод перейти на linux"* `man` на винде (и свежий mingw) ставятся из [MSYS2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30069830/how-can-i-install-mingw-w64-and-msys2). Хотя, опять же, из `--help` можно все то же самое выудить.